# ion-input onclick in ionic 4 angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I have a view with a ion-input inside a form:

```
      <form class="inputs-in-block" [formGroup]="userForm">
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Username" (click)='onClickFuntion($event)'></ion-input>
      </form>
```

I want to catch the onClick event after it is fired, but I do not manage to achieve it because after clicking on the input, the `onClickFunction($event)` is not called.
This is the definition of the function:

```
onClickFunction(event) {
  console.log('Event caught');
}
```

I have tried without the event and it is not working either.

Is the click event available for s in the latest version?
Any idea to solve it?

Comment: Are you testing the click on a device or in your browser?

Comment: Yes, in my browser

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a typo:

You have in your template:

```
(click)='onClickFuntion($event)'
```

But in your ts file :

```
onClickFunction(event) {
  console.log('Event caught');
}
```

onClickFuntion <-> onClickFunction ... see the "c"

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to send it as well from the `template`. That's missing from your template. `(click)='onClickFuntion($event)`

```
<ion-input 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="Username" 
  (click)='onClickFuntion($event)'>
</ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use `ionClick` to trigger click event.

You'r code should work if you do below changes

```
<form class="inputs-in-block" [formGroup]="userForm">
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Username" (ionClick)='onClickFuntion($event)'></ion-input>
      </form>
```